# custom output path from Azure Stream analytics

Tags: azure, path, azure-data-lake, azure-stream-analytics

I have an event hub which receives telemetry data from different devices.  I created a stream analytics job to process this data and output it to various sinks (Power BI, Cosmos DB and Data Lake).  While creating the data lake output I found that I couldn't set the output path based on the message payload. The path I can set inside the sink is of the format: [folder_structure]/{date}{time}. I need a very specific folder structure which would check the message payload and put the file in the specified location.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This capability is currently available in private preview - for output to blob storage. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/4-new-features-now-available-in-azure-stream-analytics/

If this is something you can use, please provide details at the following url. we will add you to the preview program. 
https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR8zMnUkKzk5Elg9i6hoUmJVUNDhIMjJESFdVNDhRODNMTVZTNDVIR0w2Qi4u